# Nested if-statement not working properly (python)

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

Here's my code:

```
#Greeting
print('\n---Automatic Troubleshooter---\n')

#UserInput
userInput = input('Are you having issues with your Wi-Fi?: ')

#QuestionAnswer
if (userInput == 'Yes' or userInput == 'yes'):
    print('\nReboot the computer and try to connect.')
    userInput = input('Did that fix the problem?: ')
    if (userInput == 'No' or userInput == 'no'):
        print('\nReboot the router and try to connect.')
        userInput = input('Did that fix the problem?: ')
        if (userInput == 'No' or userInput == 'no'):
            print('\nMake sure the cables between the router & modem are plugged in firmly.')
            userInput = input('Did that fix the problem?: ')
            if (userInput == 'No' or userInput == 'no'):
                print('\nMove the router to a new location and try to connect.')
                userInput == input('Did that fix the problem?: ')
                if (userInput == 'No' or userInput == 'no'):
                    print('\nGet a new router.')
                else:
                    print('\nExiting program...\n')
else:
    print('\nExiting program...\n')
```

Whenever I get to the last if statement, regardless of what I input, it always prints 'Get a new router'. At first, I didn't have the first else and the last else; I just had the 'Exiting program...' outside, and in my mind, it should've worked. If the problem is fixed, it shouldn't continue with the rest and print 'Exiting program...' Also, when I change the condition it works. So when I change the last if statement's condition from 'No' and 'no' to something else, it works.

Comment: here's a tip: `if userInput.lower().strip() == 'no':`

Comment: look at one line before `if` statement. You are not assigning to `userInput`, you are comparing it. `userInput == input('Did that fix the problem?: ')`

Answer (score 2):

Before the last `if` you aren't assigning to the `userInput` variable - you have a `==` instead of a `=`. Hence, it will keep the "no" or "No" it has from the previous input, and always go to the `if` branch.

Replace the `==` with `=` and you should be OK:

```py
userInput = input('Did that fix the problem?: ')
# Here ---^
```

Comment: Wow, a syntax mistake. I'm sorry I'll delete the post since it's just a mistake. Thank you :)